# unable to read data from a text file in c

Tags: c

//here's the structure
typedef struct student
{
int rno;
char name[20];
struct subject
{
int scode;
char sname[20];
int mark;
} sub[3];
int total;
float per;
} student;

```
student s1;
    FILE *fp;
    int j;
    fp = fopen("mystudents.txt", "r");

    while (fread(&s1, sizeof(student), 1, fp))
    {
        printf("\n%d \n%s", s1.rno, s1.name);
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            printf("\n%d", s1.sub[j].mark);
        }
        printf("\n%d", s1.total);
    }
    fclose(fp);
```

Content of my file :

```
101 brian 23 45 56 124
102 abhi 32 78 90 200
```

Comment: Could you include the student structure you are using? It would make it easier to help out.

Comment: sure.  now,check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fread()` is for reading binary files, not text files (unless you're reading into a string variable). You can use `fscanf()` to parse the text file.

```
student s1;
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("mystudents.txt", "r");

while (fscanf(fp, "%d %s %d %d %d %d", &s1.rno, s1.name, &s1.sub[0].mark, &s1.sub[1].mark, &s1.sub[2].mark, &s1.total) > 0)
{
    printf("\n%d \n%s", s1.rno, s1.name);
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        printf("\n%d", s1.sub[j].mark);
    }
    printf("\n%d", s1.total);
}
fclose(fp);
```

Comment: ok , i very much appreciate ur help.Thanks

Comment: oh yeah , i'm new here forget to do that.